# Should you include files when invoking methods declared in it?

Tags: c++

Apologies, I hate to ask something so simple, but I've failed to find an answer, probably because I don't know how to describe the question concisely.

Say you have a `class X`, and want to use it in `z.cc`.

- I know you **should include** `x.h` in `z.cc` if you wish to have a field or param of type `X` so that the compiler knows how much space the field or param will require.
- I know you **should forward declare** `class X` if you wish to have a field or param of type `X*` so that the compiler is clear that the class will be declared, but doesn't need to know how much space `X` requires.
- But what about if you wish to invoke a method `X::doX()`? Does this require an include, forward declaration, or neither? I have my IDE telling me `Unused "#include "x.h""` in this situation.

E.g.

```
// x.h
class X {
  void doX() {}
}
```

```
// y.h
#include "x.h"
class Y {
  X getX() {return {};}
}
```

```
// z.cc
#include "y.h"

/* Which, if either, line is recommended:
#include "x.h"
class X;
*/

void useX(Y y) {
  auto x = y.getX();
  x.doX();
}
```

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks! my IDE must be confused then.

Comment: Since `z.cc` includes `y.h` which includes `x.h`, `x.h` is also included in `z.cc`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought I shouldn't rely on transitive includes.

Comment: *"you should forward declare class X if you wish to have a field or param of type X*"* - this is not true, in this case you should include `x.h` as well, or (if this creates a cyclic dependency or dependency on definition is not desired) an appropriate header file with forward declaration of `X`. But certainly not forward declare stuff yourself.

Comment: What IDE is that? I haven't seen an "*unused include*" warning anywhere yet.

Comment: @rustyx I know CLion grays out includes that are unused (either they have been included before, possibly indirectly, or nothing declared in them is used).

Comment: Yes, I'm using CLion. But I think it's a bit confused, because it's also telling me not to include `<string>` when I have return types & params of type `std::string` and `std::u16string`.

Comment: Personally I tend to not include header files that I already include in other header files, even standard or system header files. The key is that it has to be done in one of *my* header files. But as noted first, it's what I *personally* do. This is up to ones own personal preferences, or company style-guides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should you include files when invoking methods declared in it?

Yes.

> But what about if you wish to invoke a method X::doX()? Does this require an include, forward declaration, or neither?

Definition of the class is required to call member functions of the class.

---

Automatic type deduction can easily hide the types that we depend on. If we were to rewrite:

```
auto x = y.getX();
```

to explicitly use the type that `auto` would be deduced to:

```
X x =  y.getX();
```

We can now easily see that we define a variable of type `X`, so it has become clear that we depend on the definition of `X`.

We should avoid relying on transitive inclusions, thus we should directly include the header that defines `X`. An exception to this might be a case where `y.h` is explicitly documented to define `X`, in which case the author of `y.h` who should be aware of the given guarantee should know to not violate that guarantee, making the transitive inclusion safer.

---

> I know you should include x.h in z.cc if you wish to have a field or param of type X

To be precise, we don't need definition of `X` in order to declare a function with a parameter of type `X`. A declaration is sufficient. We do need the definition of `X` when defining a function with parameter of type `X`. Same applies to return types.

> I know you should forward declare class X if you wish to have a field or param of type X*

Note that when defining a function with param of type `X*`, it is quite typical that we may need to indirect through the pointer or convert it to another pointer type related to `X`, in which cases we do need the definition of `X`. But indeed, the definition is not needed to declare a function with such parameter.

Comment: OP has transitive inclusion, which is quintessential in the use case...

Comment: I would argue that in this case transitive inclusion is acceptable, as X is used through well-defined interface.

Comment: @SergeyA What if the author of y.h chooses to define the member function non-inline, and thus removes the inclusion of x.h, and then suddenly your code breaks since you relied on the transitive inclusion?

Comment: Well, they would than have to forward-declare it. And I argue the case would be weird enough that if it happens, include can be added once the error manifests itself.

Answer (score 1):

> But what about if you wish to invoke a method X::doX()? Does this require an include, forward declaration, or neither?

You can't call any function, class method or otherwise, without seeing its declaration. For a class method, this means the class definition, and that means including the header.

Without the class definition, the compiler wouldn't know whether to emit a virtual, static or non-virtual instance method call, whether any of the arguments are defaulted or should be implicitly converted ... all of this happens at the call site.

Since `z.cc` includes `y.h` and *that* includes `x.h`, then `z.cc` also includes `x.h`. This sort of transitive inclusion is visible directly if you run the preprocessor, eg. with `gcc -E`.

> I have my IDE telling me Unused "#include "x.h"" in this situation.

Your IDE is confused and wrong.

IMO it's better style to include every header directly, both for clarity/explicitness, and because it avoids any nasty surprises when refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You must include any symbol you are using either directly or transitively (or use a forward declaration where possible). Whether or not to rely on transitive includes is sort of a manner of style.

I personally would recommend that you do NOT rely on transitive includes. For a very good explanation of why, I would read [this](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use/blob/master/docs/WhyIWYU.md) link from the Include-What-You-Use project. The main points are:

- documentation of dependencies
- easier refactoring when something breaks the transitive include chain
- Fewer recompilations (depends on how your build system works)

It can be annoying having to include everything you use, but when it gets annoying it is a good signal that perhaps you need to break up your code more.